# Can we set HttpOnly flag to KEYCLOAK_SESSION cookie?

Tags: keycloak

Why does the `KEYCLOAK_SESSION` **cookie** in `Keycloak` does not have `HttpOnly` flag set in first place as against other cookies?

Comment: I believe it is done on purpose. I'm aware of this thread: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-September/011888.html and I'm pretty sure I saw this discussion also more recently, so that it may still be the case.

Answer (score 3):

As @besverino mentions in his comment, KeyCloak doesn't allow set `KEYCLOAK_SESSION` `HttpOnly` flag because KeyCloak needs to access the cookie from iFrame. Comment on this part of KeyCloak code is:

> THIS SHOULD NOT BE A HTTPONLY COOKIE!  It is used for OpenID Connect Iframe Session support!

References:

1. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/16.1.1/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/managers/AuthenticationManager.java#L751
2. https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-September/011882.html