# How to set HTTPonly and secure flag to keycloak cookie?

Tags: cookies, keycloak

After setting up the portal with Keycloak, we have checked that the 2 cookies mentioned below are missing the HTTPonly and secure flag.

- KEYCLOAK_SESSION
- KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY

Are we able to set the 2 flag via the Keyclock portal?

Have done some researching and most say to set the "requires SSL" field which we have already tried but it is still the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we set HttpOnly flag to KEYCLOAK\_SESSION cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990785/can-we-set-httponly-flag-to-keycloak-session-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand the reasons why KEYCLOAK_SESSION does not contain the HTTPonly flag I suggest visiting this link : https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-September/011882.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).